# Change date format in Datetimepicker

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui-datepicker

Where i need to change in the below code to change date format for datetimepicker in the following javascript:

http://www.google.com/codesearch#ak3vw-ODLck/packages/jQuery.UI.Combined.1.8.11/Content/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.js&q=jquery-ui-1.8.11.js&type=cs

Curently its show as dd/mm/yyyy  hh:mm:ss

But i want it to be dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: You don't. Whatever "datetime picker" plugin you're using should have an option to customize the date/time format. What plugin are you using? jQuery UI? That's only a date picker.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than changing in JQuery lib you can set the format while you call the datetimepicker control.

```
var date = $('#datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yyyy' });
```

**If at all** you want to do it in lib only then See [this line](http://www.google.com/codesearch#ak3vw-ODLck/packages/jQuery.UI.Combined.1.8.11/Content/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.js&q=jquery-ui-1.8.11.js&type=cs&l=8259) to change

```
dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy', // See format options on parseDate
```

You need to set this value to whatever you want. i.e. `dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yyyy'`

Answer (score 2):

#### Description

You can change the date format in the standard jQuery UI DatePicker using the option `dateformat`.

**You dont need to change the plugin.**

#### Sample

```
$( "#MyDatePicker" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yyyy' });
```

#### More Information

- [jQuery UI DatePicker - dateformat](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-dateFormat)